# AngularJS not working with Browsersync (Gulp)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, gulp

I'm new here and new to Gulp and Angular. I'm trying to make simple applications, just for learning purpose and I'm using multiple tutorials so i got lost in process.
I'm trying to serve AngularJS/Nodejs app with Gulps browser sync everything works fine apart from angular. I wrote in gulp file the code needed to serve app, and i copied cdn into header for angular app with script source for angular file. All i get is error like module is not injected but i did everything right, when i try this on my wamp server it works fine. I don't know what I'm doing wrong anyone here can shed some light on my app? here is error 
**"angular.js:4458 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]"**

**GULPFILE**

```
gulp.task('browserSync', function () {
    browserSync({
        server: {
            baseDir: 'app'
        }
    });
});
```

**Angular**

```
(function () {

     'use strict'

     angular.module('app', []);

     function main() {
          var vm = this;
          vm.title = "Hello";

     }
     angular
          .module('app')
          .controller('main', main);


})()
```

**HTML**

```
   <head>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
<head>
<body ng-app="app">
 <div class="container hero" ng-controller="main as vm">
        <h1>{{vm.title}}</h1>
        <p>Name :
            <input type="text" ng-model="name">
        </p>
        <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
    </div>
<body>
```

Comment: Seems you are including the "angular.js" file two times in your code?

Comment: No no first is CDN and second one is actual code for "app".

Comment: The problem is not with Gulp. You should re-review [how to set up](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02) an Angular application.

Comment: I'm reading it for a day now, i can't seem to figue out what is wrong. And it works fine on my wamp sever...can you point out my mistake?